# Is there a way to unset/remove out of stock variations from the variation select dropdown woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce to display products and there variations. I've basically a size variation for all of the products. Some of the variations have run out of stock but it still displays in the select dropdown. See the attached image:

[image: remove out of stock variation]

How do I remove/unset a variation option from select dropdown if a variation is 'Out of Stock'? I've tried using 'Hide Out of Stock' in the Woo Commerce settings though this made no difference.

**What I tried already**

```
function if_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
    if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $active;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'if_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );
```

**Update**

I checked the plugins and found that a plugin `Better variations` utilizes the exact same filter & hence this might be the reason the above code didn't worked for me.

```
function wcbvp_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
    $disable = get_option( 'wcbvp_disable_options', 'yes' );
    $show_text = get_option( 'wcbvp_show_text', 'no' );
    // Added $variation->get_stock_quantity() in 1.0.3
    if( ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() || $variation->get_stock_quantity() < 1 ) && ( $disable == 'yes' || $show_text == 'yes' ) && $variation->get_manage_stock() == 'yes' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $active;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'wcbvp_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You can check this one https://docs.iconicwp.com/article/194-disable-grey-out-out-of-stock-swatches :)

Comment: I already tried this & it didn't worked.

Comment: We require better diagnostic detail than "it did not work".